# How to migrate a KTable-KTable leftJoin with explicit state store from Kafka 0.11 to Kafka 2.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are facing a problem due to a change in the API from Kafka 0.11 to Kafka 2.0. In our 0.11-based Kafka streams application, we had a join between two `KTables[String,Something]` that used a named state store:

```scala
val joinedTable = {
    myClass1Table.leftJoin[MyClass1,MyClass2](myClass2Table,new
        MyJoiner, new MySerde[MyClass1Class2],"my-join-store")
}
```

However, when migrating to 2.0, the only way to explicitly provide a state store is the following:

```scala
val joinedTable = {
    val materialized = Materialized.as[String,MyClass1,KeyValueStore[Bytes,Array[Byte]]]("join-store").withValueSerde(new Serde[MyClass1Class2])
    myClass1Table.leftJoin[MyClass1,MyClass2](myClass2Table,new
        MyJoiner,materialized)
}
```

With this code, replacing the instance of app in production fails, because the state-store in Kafka 0.11 used probably the key serde of both myTable1 and myTable2.

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key type (key type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawKey(StateSerdes.java:174)
```

Besides performing a kafka-streams-application-reset, are there other, maybe better ways to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the key serde explicitly:

```scala
val joinedTable = {
  val materialized = Materialized
    .as[String,MyClass1,KeyValueStore[Bytes,Array[Byte]]]("join-store")
    .withKeySerde(new StringSerde())
    .withValueSerde(new Serde[MyClass1Class2])

  myClass1Table.leftJoin[MyClass1,MyClass2](myClass2Table, new MyJoiner, materialized)
}
```

Comment: I think it should be use to actually enforce usage of same keySerde as in kafka 0.11 by design, and this would not break semantics of operation (although the API has changed, which is fine)

Comment: I am not a Scala expert, so not sure. However, it seem you are coding Scala against the Java API. Since 2.0.0 Kafka Streams ships with a Scala API, too. I would recommend to use it, and assume it resolves the issue.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to say. What I am trying to say is that if you want to have the same behaviour in 0.11 and 2.0.0, you would not need to explictly specify the key serializer for the join. In 0.11, it is not needed, so it should not be needed in 2.0.0

Comment: While I agree with what you are saying, Scala is not officially supported in 0.11, thus, we don't test for compatibility for Scala, but only for Java. It seems, something was broken unintentionally, was is unfortunate :(